# properties of :hover table rows don't revert to their pre-:hover state

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to highlight rows of a table on hover with a 2px border. To prevent cells from shifting they're given a 4px padding if not selected and not hovered, 2px border and 2px padding if hovered, and a 4px border if selected.

The code can be found in this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/864wLj2L/) or pasted below.

```
td {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  font-size: 1.3rem; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
   padding: 4px;
}
tr.selected {
   border: 4px solid black; }
tr.selected td:first-child {
   padding-left : 8px; } 
tr.selected td:last-child {
   padding-right : 8px; }

tr.notselected {
     border: 0px solid black;
     padding: 4px;}

tr.notselected:hover td:first-child {
   padding-left : 9px; }
tr.notselected:hover td:last-child {
   padding-right : 9px; }
tr.notselected:hover {
   border: 2px solid black;
   padding: 2px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">Header 1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Subheader 1.1</td>
    <td>Subheader 1.2</td>
    <td>Subheader 2.1</td>
    <td>Subheader 2.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selected">
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td >10.1</td>
    <td >10.6</td>
    <td >9.1</td>
    <td >9.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="notselected">
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>12.9</td>
    <td>11.3</td>
    <td>10.1</td>
    <td>10.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="notselected">
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>8.7</td>
    <td>8.8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="notselected">
</table>
```

Instead of remaining static, the borders and contents of the rows below the hovered row shift down, remain shifted down after the row is un-hovered, but shift back up after a second hover on hover off.

Comment: To prevent the shifting, why not use `outline: 2px solid black`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CSS outlines instead of the borders/padding combination you have to prevent the rows shifting like in this [fork of your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b73edLyu/).

```
outline: 2px solid black;
```